# install Flask as a virtual environment whith virtualenv.py in 12.10

Tags: software-installation, python, virtualenv, flask

I am trying to follow this [Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) to learn flask. I have never used python before and a relatively new to linux too so sorry if I am asking a very basic question.

I have installed python version 2.7.5 and am now trying to create the virtual environment for flask.

I downloaded `virtualenv.py` and ran the command this command:

```
python virtualenv.py flask
```

Then get this error.

```
New python executable in flask/bin/python
Cannot find sdist setuptools-*.tar.gz
Cannot find sdist pip-*.tar.gz
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Managed to find a different command that worked `$ virtualenv flaskapp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem.

To solve it, I just looked for the files on google, pip-*.tar.gz and setuptools-*.tar.gz, got the latest version of each and put them in the microblog folder.

Got this:

```
New python executable in flask/bin/python
Installing Setuptools.........................................................................................................................................done.
Installing Pip.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
```